# How do I solve protesting about high rent?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have a lot of people in front of my office complaining about too high rent. 
I can barely do any phone calls because of their screaming all day.

How do I solve this problem?

As far as I am aware you can't modify any rents...

Comment: [The rent is too damn high!](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/188/051/alg_jimmy_mcmillan_1.jpg?1318985801)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe unemployment causes the complaints about high rent. Sims will protest high rent when they are running out of money to pay for rent.